# Default uncheck "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file"

Tags: windows-7, regedit

Is there any way to have the "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" option unchecked by default?

I found [this](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-disable-always-use-the-selected-program-to-open-this-kind-of-file-option-in-open-with-dialog-box/) method to have the option disabled. I haven't tried it yet, but that's not what I'm looking for; I'm hoping to have that option enabled but unchecked by default.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For what reason? What are you trying to do that requires you to open files with a program other than the default frequently?

Comment: @Karan: Say for playing a large .mp4.crdownload while it is being downloaded.

Comment: So can't you drag and drop onto a media player? Or add the player to the Send To menu?

Comment: @Karan: I can. That's not the point. I'd like this option better.

Comment: Why not add your player to the context menu or even the Open with menu for .crdownload files then? That way you won't have to browse for the program every time.

Comment: There is no such option at this moment. You can either have the checkbox checked or remove the whole checkbox.

Comment: There is a suggestion to add this option: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/always-use-this-app-to-open-files-checkbox-on/07308ebc-d719-4a39-b0fd-0dc9a9477ccc